# how to run old IE browser in android?

Tags: android, legacy

I have to run a legacy web system in android, but new browsers are not compatible with this system, however IE is compatible with this system. so please let me know how to use old IE in android?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run IE in some windows emulator, like https://sourceforge.net/projects/limbopcemulator/

This is joke ... in the first place I don't think the emulator would be good enough to make this work. Even if it would, WinXP and old IE is security hole plus android+emulator doesn't sound like stable environment, so overall it would either not work, or be extremely vulnerable to any attack from basically any kid around.

Drop the legacy web system, it's over (like 5+ years over).